# Cannot set CornerRadius value from static resource

Tags: silverlight, xaml, resourcedictionary, cornerradius

I have defined a static resource:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
   xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
   mc:Ignorable="d" 
   Width="255" 
   Height="300">

   <UserControl.Resources>
      <sys:Double x:Key="CornerRadiusValue">5</sys:Double>
   </UserControl.Resources>
...
```

Later on in XAML file, I am trying to use that value when setting top left corner radius for a border:

```
<Border 
   Width="40"
   Height="30"
   BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" 
   BorderBrush="Red">
      <Border.CornerRadius>
         <CornerRadius TopLeft="{StaticResource CornerRadiusValue}" />
      </Border.CornerRadius>
</Border>
```

In design time, everything works fine and changing the value for `CornerRadiusValue` static resource changes the corner radius on a border. However, when I want to run this, I get an `XamlParseException` exception with the message:

> Cannot set read-only property `System.Windows.CornerRadius.TopLeft'.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Please note that I do need to be specific about the top left corner. The other corners should be bound to some other static resource values...

Comment: Make it a DynamicResource if you want to change it at runtime.

Comment: ~10 years later, your solution works without issue. Maybe they changed how CornerRadius is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.cornerradius.topleft%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> You can set this value in XAML, but only as part of the attribute syntax for properties that take a [CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.cornerradius%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), or as initialization text of a [CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.cornerradius%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) object element. See XAML sections and Remarks sections of [CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.cornerradius%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

You could try to bind the whole `CornerRadius` property and use a converter to get all the resources and create a `CornerRadius` instance from them using the constructor.

e.g. using only one value:

```
<Border Name="bd" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
    <Border.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="CR_TopLeft">5</sys:Double>
    </Border.Resources>
    <Border.CornerRadius>
        <Binding ElementName="bd">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <vc:CornerRadiusConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Border.CornerRadius>
    <Button>!</Button>
</Border>
```

```cs
public class CornerRadiusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var resourceSource = (FrameworkElement)value;
        var topLeft = (double)resourceSource.Resources["CR_TopLeft"];
        return new CornerRadius(topLeft, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You could propbably make this more generic by searching for the resources going up the tree and not directly targeting the object on which the resources are defined.

*(This is a Silverlight-only problem, in WPF your code works just fine, if you have a Silverlight question please avoid the WPF tag unless the problem actually exists in WPF)*

Answer (score 7):

```
<sys:Double x:Key="ScrollbarHandleCrValue">3</sys:Double>
<CornerRadius x:Key="ScrollbarHandleCornerRadius" 
   TopLeft="{StaticResource ScrollbarHandleCrValue}" 
   TopRight="{StaticResource ScrollbarHandleCrValue}" 
   BottomRight="{StaticResource ScrollbarHandleCrValue}" 
   BottomLeft="{StaticResource ScrollbarHandleCrValue}" />

...
<Border Name="Border"
   CornerRadius="{StaticResource ScrollbarHandleCornerRadius}" 
   Background="{StaticResource ScrollbarHandleColor}"
   BorderBrush="Transparent"
   BorderThickness="1" />
...
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, I just couldn't work this one out, anybody who comes across this should commit to memory for use on anything else which involves XAML of this nature =)

Answer (score 1):

I believe `CornerRadius` properties are not `DependencyProperties`, so they cannot be set through a binding.

The two alternatives I can think of is to use a `MultiConverter` which accepts the parameters of the `Border` object, and desired `CornerRadius`, or to create a custom DependencyProperty for the `CornerRadius`. Both methods would require you to set the value in code-behind.

Comment: @HB Hrrm I thought it was a Struct. Actually I see what you mean, `Border.CornerRadius` is a dependency property, however the properties on the `CornerRadius` are not. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The type `CornerRadius` is of course a struct, but `Border.CornerRadius` is a DP, also this is not a binding, you can use other markup extensions (like `StaticResource`) on any property.

Comment: @HB Hrrm I learn something new everyday. I never really thought about it, but I suppose it makes sense since `StaticResource` gets resolved once, so a `DependencyProperty` isn't needed.